# Error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, sql

Estoy tomando un curso de HTML y php y ahora que estaba haciendo algunos cambios en mi código me aparece el siguiente error:

Estaba comprobando si faltaba algún punto y coma pero después de varias veces revisar el código, realmente no logro encontrar el problema.

Por favor ayuda, que llevo harto rato metida en lo mismo:

```html
 if(strlen($POST['name'] >= 1 && strlen($POST['last_name'] >= 1 
   && strlen($POST['second_last_name'] >= 1) && strlen($POST['id'] >= 1
   && strlen($POST['address'] >= 1 && strlen($POST['phone'] >= 1){
    $id=trim($_POST['id'])
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $last_name=trim($_POST['last_name']);
    $second_last_name=trim($_POST['second_last_name']);
    $address=trim($_POST['address']);
    $phone=trim($_POST['phone']);
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO contratista(id, name, last_name, second_last_name, adrees, phone) VALUES ('$id','$name','$last_name', 'second_last_name','address','phone')";

    $resultado=mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
    if($resultado){
     ?>
     <h3 class = "ok">Contratista agregado correctamente</h3>
     <?php
    }else{
     ?>
     <h3 class = "bad">¡UPS, ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
     <?php
    }else{
     ?>
     <h3 class = "bad">¡UPS, Porfavor complete los campos!</h3>
     <?php
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta un `;` en la siguiente linea:

```
$id=trim($_POST['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores:

1. Casi ningún `strlen` está cerrado.
2. Falta un punto y coma en la fila `$id=trim($_POST['id'])`
3. Los `if` están mal anidados. Tienes el `else` principal dentro de uno de los `if` internos. Identa el código adecuadamente para que puedas ver con facilidad este tipo de errores de bloque.

Prueba así:

```
<?php
    if(strlen($POST['name']) >= 1 && strlen($POST['last_name']) >= 1 
            && strlen($POST['second_last_name'] >= 1) && strlen($POST['id']) >= 1
            && strlen($POST['address']) >= 1 && strlen($POST['phone']) >= 1) {
                $id=trim($_POST['id']);
                $name = trim($_POST['name']);
                $last_name=trim($_POST['last_name']);
                $second_last_name=trim($_POST['second_last_name']);
                $address=trim($_POST['address']);
                $phone=trim($_POST['phone']);
                $consulta = "INSERT INTO contratista(id, name, last_name, second_last_name, adrees, phone) VALUES ('$id','$name','$last_name', 'second_last_name','address','phone')";

            $resultado=mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
            if($resultado){
            ?>
                <h3 class = "ok">Contratista agregado correctamente</h3>
            <?php
            }else{
            ?>
                <h3 class = "bad">¡UPS, ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
            <?php
            }

    }else{              
    ?>
            <h3 class = "bad">¡UPS, Porfavor complete los campos!</h3>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, lo seguiré teniendo en cuenta.

Comment: @MarianaLopez ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!